# When to use to-be verb and when to not using to-be verb?

Tags: tense, verbs, present-tense, parts-of-speech

I'm still learning Part of Speech and some tenses, but in the basic, I got confused. Like this, "I work" and "I am Work" Why is the one using "am" and the other one is not using "am". Another example is "She studies computer science" why the sentence is not using "is" which matches with "she" (She is studies). When to use the to-be verb and when to not using the to-be verb?

Comment: Your examples are confusing. Did you mean “I am working” and “She is studying” or are you trying to communicate something else?

Comment: That's the location where I got confused. To-be verb such as "am, is, are" are used with partners such as I with am, you with are, etc. But sometimes i see a sentence with the to-be verb like "I play chess once a week" why is the sentence is not using to-verb "am" which match with the "I". Or in another way why the sentence is not "I am play chess once a week". When to must use the "am" and when to not use the "am". That's my question.

Comment: _To be_ is sometimes used as an [auxiliary verb](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/auxiliary-verbs). We say _I work in a factory_ (that is my job). _I am working there today_, where _am working_ is the continuous tense meaning that the action is in progress at this time. We don't say _I am work_. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is about the two tenses **present simple** and **present continuous**.

[This page](https://learnenglishkids.britishcouncil.org/grammar-practice/present-simple-and-present-continuous) at the British Council might be a good place to learn about them. They also have courses. If you want to do one, there seems to be a special offer today [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous). (I don't work for them!)

These two BBC pages might also be helpful: [Here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/tgg/unit-1/session-2) and [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/lower-intermediate/unit-2/session-2).